# Why did two characters have to go to Lake Tahoe to get married?

Tags: greys-anatomy

In Grey's Anatomy, series 10, episode 13, two people decide to drive to Lake Tahoe to get married.

Why did they have to go to there? Is it something to do with going to another state?  (Do marriage laws differ between American states?) Or was it just to go somewhere different?  It seems like Canada would be closer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Nevada](http://www.usmarriagelaws.com/search/united_states/nevada/) has no waiting period for marriage. You can apply for a license with as little identification as a Drivers License, pay as little as $35 in some counties (generally $60) and get married immediately. You do not even have to be a Nevada Resident.

[Washington State](http://www.usmarriagelaws.com/search/united_states/washington/) has a 3-day waiting period after the license is granted, but most other details follow the Nevada law. You do not have to be a Washington State resident, either.

[Canada](http://marriage.about.com/cs/marriagelicenses/p/canada.htm) Also, has no waiting period, and it seems it is only slightly stricter in indentification. It also bears no residency requirement.

So, Canada would be closer, but maybe they didn't have passports? I don't remember the 2 of them mentioning they had ever left the country. Maybe they just didn't want to deal with Canada, and wanted the simplest U.S. state to marry in. Maybe they just like Lake Tahoe.

Nearby states [waiting periods](http://usmarriagelaws.com/search/united_states/waiting_period_marriage_license/index.shtml)